# How to use k-means algorithm to do attribute clustering after NER?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, named-entity-recognition

I am reading [this paper](http://aircconline.com/ijnlc/V8N5/8519ijnlc03.pdf) and in 3.2.1 sub-section, first paragraph last three lines,

> To map the named entity candidates to the
>   standard attribute names, we employed the k-means algorithm to cluster the identified named
>   entities by computing the cosine similarities between them based on Term Frequency–Inverse
>   Document Frequency (TFIDF)."

Can anyone explain what does that mean? If possible give an example about the implementation scenario.

Comment: Are looking for explanations about what is Kmeans and what is TFIDF? Or are you trying to understand what are name entity candidates and standard attribute names?

Comment: @Roim I'm good with Kmeans and TFIDF but little unsure on how he clustered the identitied named entities. So , the NER model will already be able to get skills, education etc then why did the paper proposed this extra step. Why is the purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not completely sure what they mean; the best solution is to directly ask the paper's authors about this. But it seems that the clustering has been performed to do something related to [entity linking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_linking).

Entity linking is the process of disambiguating the named entities discovered in the text by matching them with the unique identities (e.g. Wikipedia articles or database entries). For example, "Washington" can be linked to the city "Washington, D.C", the state "Washington", or the person "George Washington". On the other hand, the strings "Stanford", "Stanford University", "Leland Stanford Junior University", "LSJU", "Stanford U.", "Stanford uni", "University of Stanford", Stanford.edu", "Stanfurd", and [a few more](https://dispenser.info.tm/~dispenser/cgi-bin/rdcheck.py?page=Stanford_University) do refer to the same institution. This information is not provided by pure NER models, because they can tell you only that e.g. in `I graduated from Stanford U. in 2010`, `Stanford U` is a school - but not that it is some specific school.

You may want to use NEL, because NER model predicts only that "Stanford U" is the name of a educational institution, or that "TeslaMotors" is the name of a company. Then the NEL model predicts that "Stanford U" really means "Stanford University", and "TeslaMotors" really means "Tesla, inc.". So you can think that named entity linking somehow "refines" the recognized entities. It is useful, for example, if you perform some downstream task (e.g. classification of resumes) using the found entities, and "Tesla, inc." is present in the training sample, whereas "TeslaMotors" isn't. In this situation, named entity linking will improve the generalizing ability of the downstream model, because after NEL both entities will be treated exactly the same way.

The authors of the paper, however, don't seem to have the database for all their domain-specific entities (schools, degrees, skills, job position etc.), or don't have a labeled dataset to train a model for entity linking. Therefore, instead of classical entity linking, they just merge similar occurrences of entites into clusters, hoping that the strings that end up in the same cluster do really refer to the same identity.

This approach may seem crude, but it is better than no linking at all, and it can provide a good starting point for manually labelling/linking the clusters and thus creating a dataset for training a supervised model for entity linking.

Comment: Thank you for the response. The first thing I tried was to contact the authors but couldn't find any contact info. I tried my very best. I still can't understand what entity linking means. Isn't NER model in this case already predict skills, schools, degrees, job-positions etc.., we call easily extract those directly from NER model isn't it? Why do we need entity linking in this case?

Comment: Entity linking is needed to narrow down the space of possible predicted entities. 
For example, you may find it useful to know that the entities "Stanford", "Stanford University", "Leland Stanford Junior University", "LSJU", "Stanford U.", "Stanford uni", "University of Stanford", Stanford.edu" and even "Stanfurd" do refer to the same institution.

Comment: So I think I understood that, but what about how did they merge similar occurrences of entities into clusters. Can you explain a little more in depth on how to implement it. I'm currently working on this paper.

Comment: You can apply any "text clustering" algorithm here - e.g. the one from this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61748673/merge-nearly-similar-rows-with-help-of-spacy/61878598#61878598, or the one from the scikit-learn example https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/text/plot_document_clustering.html, or any other text clustering algorithm you can Google for.

Comment: I think I still can't totally get why it is required? I hope you have read the paper, first they segmented the resumes into multiple sections (i..e, personal, work, projects, skills etc.) right? Now, I will train an NER model and then predict the entities into those subsection isn't it? Like, if we take work sub-section my NER model will predict work duration (or) company name because I trained the NER model. So, now how does this entity linking helpful more. I already got what is required isn't it?

Comment: The NER model predicts that "Stanford U" is the name of a educational institution, or that "TeslaMotors" is the name of a company. Then the NEL model predicts that "Stanford U" really means "Stanford University", and "TeslaMotors" really means "Tesla, inc.".  So you can think that named entity linking somehow "refines" the recognized entities.

Comment: It is useful, for example, if you perform some downstream task (e.g. classification of resumes) using the found entities, and "Tesla, inc." is present in the training sample, whereas "TeslaMotors" isn't. In this situation, named entity linking will improve the generalizing ability of the downstream model, because after NEL both entities will be treated exactly the same way.

Comment: Okay. So, we perform NEL after NER to group similar predictions. Just one doubt regarding NER model so if we train an NER model with data Stanford U as an entity will it be able to predict Stanford University on test data? Here Stanford university is not seen in train-data.

Comment: Is there a medium I can contact you? I am implementing NER model and have few doubts.

Comment: I am @cointegrated in Telegram.